# How to import multiple images to a Django app

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model with a `title` and an `asset` field. `asset` is a `FileField`.

This is not something user facing, it's only available through the Admin and I can import the images there, one by one. But there's hundreds of them and I'm looking for a way to do bulk import/upload with the `title` being the filename without the extension. Is something like this available in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in the same folder, load them from the path, and use a forloop on the backend?

```
import imageio
path = "enter the path here"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
     im = imageio.imread(file)
     ModelName(title=str(x), asset=im.save())
```

Something like that.